# How to make this using switch?

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I have a `blade` layout for generating messages. How to simplify this?

```
@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
        <strong>{!! $message !!}</strong>
    </div>
@endif

@if ($message = Session::get('danger'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
        <strong>{!! $message !!}</strong>
    </div>
@endif

@if ($message = Session::get('warning'))
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-block">
        <strong>{!! $message !!}</strong>
    </div>
@endif

@if ($message = Session::get('info'))
    <div class="alert alert-info alert-block">
        <strong>{!! $message !!}</strong>
    </div>
@endif

@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        Please check the form below for errors
    </div>
@endif
```

I guess I have to make an array `['success', 'error', 'warning', 'info']` and ckeck if any value from it present as argument of `Session::get()`, than use `switch()` to pass that value as class name.

So I want to make it usable like

```
@if ($message = Session::get($type))
    <div class="alert alert-<?=$type; ?> alert-block">
        <strong>{!! $message !!}</strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@switch($message)
  @case(Session::get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
      <strong>{!! $message !!}</strong>
    </div>
  @break

  @case(Session::get('danger'))
   <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
     <strong>{!! $message !!}</strong>
   </div>
  @break

  @default
    <span>Something went wrong, please try again</span>
@endswitch
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've explainde not properly. I updatet my question.

Comment: @DoIGetAnything try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897508/switch-in-laravel-5-blade

Comment: I know how to make switch. I don't know how to check if `Session` has certain types (last paragraph in my question).